# if exist on update sentence mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the next query:

```
UPDATE a, b, c SET a.deleted=1, b.deleted=1, c.deleted=1 
WHERE a.id='$aID' AND a.com='$comID' AND b.areID=a.id AND c.areID=a.id
```

The problem is that sometimes c.areID is not going to exist also it goes the same for b.areID, so, is there any sentence life if exist or something like that in MySQL?

Comment: not going to exists is NULL value.

Comment: To my knowledge there's no such thing as a `LEFT JOIN` inside an `UPDATE` statement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "does not exist" you mean that it can be NULL.

```
UPDATE a, b, c SET a.deleted=1, b.deleted=1, c.deleted=1 
WHERE a.com='$comID' AND a.id='$aID' AND (b.areID=a.id OR b.areID IS NULL) 
AND (c.areID=a.id or c.areID IS NULL)
```

If you don't want to update with NULL values then your query should be OK as when areID is NULL then it doesn't match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to set the `deleted` column of `a`, as well as the `deleted` column of any corresponding (child) rows in both `b` and `c`.

To accompish that, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE a
  LEFT JOIN b ON b.areID=a.id
  LEFT JOIN c ON c.areID=a.id
   SET a.deleted=1
     , b.deleted=1
     , c.deleted=1
 WHERE a.id='$aID'
   AND a.com='$comID'
```

The comma join operators in the original statement are equivalent to "INNER JOIN". When a child row does not exist in either `b` or `c`, the original statement does not update any rows.

By using an outer join, the statement can update the row(s) from `a` even when a child row does not exist in `b` and/or `c`, as well was updating an corresponding child rows in `b` and and `c`.